# Git bash doesn't recognize 'rev' command

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-bash

I am trying to use a function that shortens my bash prompt. I have added it in `.bash_profile`:

```
function last_two_dirs {
   pwd |rev| awk -F / '{print $1,$2}' | rev | sed s_\ _/_
}

export PS1='$(last_two_dirs) $(__git_ps1) ➡  '
```

But I get an error `bash: rev: command not found` everytime I launch git bash.

I have set the `PATH` correctly since other commands work correctly except `rev`. Is `rev` not part of git bash? Or is there any other way to show only the parent and the current directory for the bash prompt?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't `export` your `PS1`. It's supposed to be set only for interactive shells and would typically would go into `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `rev` is an external command (a separate executable), not part of the shell itself; it's thus not part of **any** version of bash, but something that exists (or doesn't) depending on whether your it's been separately installed (or included with your operating system &c).

Comment: BTW, using command substitutions in your prompt is a really bad idea -- they're *slow*, and especially slow on Windows. Much better to use only native shell logic (and no command substitutions at all; bash has a `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook you can use to specify a function that changes PS1, which if done right will involve no forking subprocesses at all).

Comment: Use `\w` and `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me -

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='case $PWD in
        $HOME) HPWD="~";;
        $HOME/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        $HOME/*) HPWD="~/${PWD##*/}";;
        /*/*/*) HPWD="${PWD#"${PWD%/*/*}/"}";;
        *) HPWD="$PWD";;
      esac'
PS1='$HPWD \$'
```

referred from [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216953/show-only-current-and-parent-directory-in-bash-prompt)

Comment: Consider using a *function* instead of a script in a variable! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938151/1765658)

Answer (score 6):

Your environment doesn't seem to have the `rev` command. However, you don't need it, there are built-in facilities for what you want to do.

To get the current working directory in your `PS1`, use [`\w`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt):

```
PS1='\w\$ '
```

This gets you the full path, so your prompt will look something like

```
~/tinker/so/subdir/subsubdir$
```

Now, set the [`$PROMPT_DIRTRIM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fDIRTRIM) variable to the number of trailing directories to retain:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
```

This will get you a prompt like

```
~/.../subdir/subsubdir$
```

Comment: I considered DIRTRIM but just wanted something more minimalistic without the dots and stuff to make the prompt clean looking

Comment: @FatehAK For my own prompt, I do something similar: I replace all directory names but the current one with just the first three characters, so `/path/to/some/nested/directory` would show up as `/pat/to/som/nes/directory`. I use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to create my prompt, see [here](https://github.com/bewuethr/dotfiles/blob/d9521fb948277a9c8d1f2db76d5d7aa9621357ae/myprompt.bash#L194).

Comment: `...` seems like a small price to pay to make it clear that you are eliding the full directory and avoiding additional clutter in your `bash` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

## [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function around `$PWD`

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there are lot of trick and features you could use to make this a lot quicker and efficient

#### Simply two last path level:

```
last_two_dirs() {
    local left=${PWD%/*};
    echo "${PWD#${left%/*}/}"
}
```

#### More complex: first and last level:

```
path_parts() {
    local APATH
    IFS=/ read -a APATH <<<"$PWD"
    if ((${#APATH[@]}>3)) ;then
        echo "/${APATH[1]}..${APATH[-1]}"
    else
        echo "$PWD"
    fi
}
```

#### Another *special case*

Les imagine your path in this kind:

```
/srv/dist/invoices-2019/data-2019-02-10/seq-123
```

To trim all part of path until first dash:

```
path_dash_Trim () {
    local APATH;
    IFS=/ read -a APATH <<< "$PWD";
    APATH="${APATH[*]#*-}";
    echo "${APATH// /\/}"
}
```

will render

```
/srv/dist/2019/2019-02-10/123
```

### Fork performance issue

In order to reduce performance issue, there is a proper way to eliminate forks ( `var=$(commnand)` ): Set variable in function:

Simply replace

```
echo ${PWD#${left%/*}/}
```

by

```
printf -v $1 %s "${PWD#${left%/*}/}"
```

or better:

```
printf -v ${1:-myResult} '%s' "${PWD#${left%/*}/}"
```

Sample:

```
last_two_dirs() { local left=${PWD%/*};printf -v $1 "%s" "${PWD#${left%/*}/}" ;}
last_two_dirs result
printf -v $1 %s "$result"
```

or

```
path_parts() {
    local APATH
    IFS=/ read -a APATH <<<"$PWD"
    if ((${#APATH[@]}>3)) ;then
        printf -v $1 %s "/${APATH[1]}..${APATH[-1]}"
    else
        printf -v $1 %s "$PWD"
    fi
}
```

and so on...

Then

```
export -f path_parts
PROMPT_COMMAND='path_parts PS1&&PS1+=" \\$ "'
```

or even simply dedicated function:

```
myPrompt() {
    local APATH fmt='%s\[\e];%s\a\] $ '
    IFS=/ read -a APATH <<<"$PWD"
    if ((${#APATH[@]}>4)) ;then
        printf -v PS1 "$fmt" "/${APATH[1]}..${APATH[-2]}/${APATH[-1]}"{,}
    else
        printf -v PS1 "$fmt" "$PWD"{,}
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=myPrompt
```

Comment: Nota: I posted this only after you comment about `$DIRTRIM` on [Benjamin W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937575/1765658)

Comment: ``foo() { echo bar; }; baz=$(foo)`` doesn't fork on my bash, it detects the builtin and runs it inline.

Answer (score 1):

Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) tools, it has the tools you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
function last_two_dirs () 
{ 
        awk -F/ '{print ((NF>1)?$(NF-1)"/":"")""$NF}' <<< $PWD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
pwd | sed -r 's|.*/([^/]+/[^/]+)$|\1|'
```

instead